# Easiest way to delay

Tags: c#, .net

What is the easiest/simplest way to delay inside a function without having to delay the main thread? 
This is what I am trying to do is similar to this:

```
    private void FallingToggle(bool a)
    {
        a = true;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        a = false;
    }
```

But I found that it froze the whole program. 
Is there a way around this? Or is there a more simple way to approach this?

Comment: This code suggests serious design flaws in your project, you should reconsider the need to arbitrarily sleep for 1000.  What is it you want to do?

Comment: That really is the "easiest" method to delay (and only general approach to delay *synchronously*). However, as seen, that *does* block the current thread. Otherwise, consider moving to an *asynchronous* model (e.g. Timer and callbacks).

Comment: Can you explain why you want to delay like this? It smells fishy.

Comment: My reason for a function like this is because I would like to limit how often a user can run a function (e.g. eliminate users spamming a send button in a messaging program)

Comment: You would need to create a timer and on tick event disable code/button that does Send

Comment: Just record the time that the button was last used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Responding to your comment, there are many ways what you're trying to do can be achieved.

One way is to record the time when the action occurs the first time (this can be achieved using [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)). Then, if any subsequent actions occur within one second of the recorded time, return immediately. Example:

```
DateTime lastActionTime = DateTime.Now;

// ...

if ((DateTime.Now - lastActionTime).Milliseconds < 1000)
{
    // Too soon to execute the action again
    return;
}

// Do whatever the action does...
```

Another way to do this, in the case that you want to disable a button for one second, is to use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) (there are several timers in the .NET Framework, I'm using the Winforms version here). Once the action occurs, you disable the button or other UI element, and then start a `Timer`, with an interval of one second. Once the timer goes off, you can reenable the UI element, allowing the user to execute the action again. Example:

```
// In a constructor or something
timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 milliseconds
timer.Tick += (s, e) => 
{
    button.Enabled = true;
    timer.Stop();
};

// ...

void OnButtonClick()
{
    button.Enable = false;
    timer.Start();

    // Do whatever the button does...
}
```

The latter is what you would use in a GUI, the former could be used in something like a game.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way..

In the function call event after `a = true;` start a new thread. And put

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
    a = false;
```

in the new thread.

I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: Shouldn't be using thread.sleep. The timer option together with a disable button option that 'mgbowen' has provided in his answer is a better design.